# Speedtest High priority: Enable Browser caching

Tags: magento, caching, e-commerce, browser-cache

I'm using Magento 1.7 and i have recently switched my shop to a new Cloud Computing Hoster. To check my shops performance I run several pagespeed test. And every result gave me the same High priority: **Enable Browser caching!**

So far I have activated every single cache at System -> Cache. So I don't know why my shop does not make use of Browser Caching.

By switching to the new Hoster I deleted the files stored in the `/var` directory. This was mentioned in a short Tutorial for switching a Magento Shop to a server.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This recommendation has nothing to do with Magento's caching.

There are browser cache directives that can be sent to tell the client's browser how long to keep page objects like images, media content, page html, stylesheets, javascripts, etc in the local client browser cache before trying to refresh. These directives are enabled through DSO modules (apache web server), server configuration and .htaccess file entries.

The .htaccess file installed by Magento has the following section which is only activated if your web server is loading the [mod_expires  DSO Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

[More information from Yahoo on setting Expires directives](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)

**ADDED**

How to tell what modules are being loaded. This only works if the php interpreter is being run through loading the **mod_php5** DSO module in Apache. Create a `phpinfo()` configuration dump page and look for the following:

[image]

Once the expires module is working and paying attention to your .htaccess entries, you can use an addon like LiveHttpHeaders in Firefox to view the HTTP server request/response headers similar to as follows:

[image]

Comment: So for example this is a Speedtest from Magento's Demostore:

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#url=http_3A_2F_2Fdemo.magentocommerce.com_2F&mobile=false

On the left you so below the red High priority section, "Browser-Caching". By clicking on this recommendation you see a list of all ressources which dont use an expiry date. (This is the same i get with my own shop). To solve this problem, i have the set an expiry date in the .htaccess for every item listed there? Or is there a possibility to set a global one for my entire Magento shop? Thank you!

Comment: Or is there a common solution the Magento community makes use of?

Comment: The provided link is of a demo web store that likely doesn't have the expires function turned on in .htaccess. To solve the problem, make sure your .htaccess file has the entries in the above code clip which sets `ExpiresDefault` to the object access date **plus one year** and turns `ExpiresActive On`. That is the common solution.

Comment: Hi, i have added the entries in my .htaccess and double checked it. After uploading the changed file i've run the pagetest again, but nothing changed, i still get the same recommendation. How can i check if my Hoster has activated mod_expires on his server? What else could have gone wrong? Do i have to specify filetypes, like "css, jpg, js ..."? Thank you very much!

Comment: In my phpinfo i found this: "session.cache_expire = 180" is this relevant?

Comment: The session.cache_expire has to do with the user session. PHP has so many implementations, if it's running as fastCGI (separate process), the only way is to ask the hosting provider, if the php interpreter is being loaded as an apache module, `phpinfo()` will have a section called **apache2handler** (see added image above). Originally, expires wasn't working on this test system and I had to load it so I could see it in the headers.

Comment: Oddly, my Magento .htaccess file was missing the "ExpiresActive On" directive. Adding this fixed my config.

Answer (score 3):

**Copy and paste at the end of .htaccess file to improve laverage browser caching.**

[image]

```html
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```